# How to make a Strapi entry with relation included through REST Api Post

Tags: rest, strapi

I have two collection types that are connected with a relation :
[image]

[image]

Where Student has many Posts
and When I make a post trought the admin panel I don't have any problems.
I even figured out how to assign media with a POST request
which is done by giving the media id.
But I still can't figure out how to link the relation on post creation with the request
I tried giving the id of the user but it comes out empty also tried UID empty again

[image]

And the JSON request :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In request you have `Student` with a capital `S`, but in strapi admin it is `student` with lowercase `s`. You should use the same naming convention through all the properties to avoid such a problems.

Comment: Thank you so much , how did I not notice this